# receive and decode H.264 live stream in Android

Tags: android, video, h.264

I am evaluating the possibility of displaying a continuous H.264 live feed (RTSP) on an Android device (2.3+ or even 4.0). I need the delay time (source to display, can assume source encoding to have zero delay) to be within 1 second or so. Wonder if anybody has done this already? What would be a good approach to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just give it a try. H264 is supported by android and is even hardware-accelerated on the latest generation of (upper and  middle class devices). There is the MediaPlayer class, which can be used to play video files and it also supports the streaming of http and rtsp URIs.

Comment: I've tested the MediaPlayer class. However it seems to restrict a buffer size such that the play back is always lagging behind real scene by around 5 seconds which is the major concern I have. Any way to improve on this one?